# Why does Ubuntu 12.04 64bit recognize a symlink as a binary file?

Tags: symbolic-link

I have two files. One file has the name `gcc` and is a shell file. Another file has the name `g++` and contains data like this:

```
!&lt;symlink&gt;ÿþg c c
```

I can run the shell file gcc but the file g++ cannot run. When I try I see this error:

```
bash: ./g++: cannot execute binary file
```

Can anyone explain why I see this error?

output of `ls -l` for this file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 May 18 11:43 g++
```

Comment: is that what it says when you use `ls -l`?

Comment: No, when I run by command ./g++

Comment: so what does it say if you use `ls -l` on each of those? Also what directory are you in when you execute `./g++`?

Comment: I don't understand what you say. My english is not good, sorry about this. But I have record my error to show for you, this is link: https://youtu.be/QPd8H82nPcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `ls -l` in the directory (in your video), you can see that `g++` is not a symlink. Here is what a symlink from my system looks like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    10 May 28 20:20 modules.conf -> ../modules
```

Note the string at the beginning: `lrwxrwxrwx` - all symlinks have this.

You can also tell that your file `g++` is not a symlink, because when you open it, instead of seeing the contents of the file it points to, you see some other data.

If a file is not readable, for example it doesn't have a known header or [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) `file name-of-file` will return `data` and programs may decide it is a 'binary file'. Type `man file` for more about this.

To workaround this part of your problem just replace the files by making symlinks to replace the broken files, for example:

To create a symlink to your file `gcc` named `g++` in the directory do this:

```
ln -s gcc g++
```

And then `ls -l` to check. You should see something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 zanna zanna    3 May 31 08:38 g++ -> gcc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zanna zanna    0 May 31 08:38 gcc
```

But whether your envsetup script will then run is... another question.

**How did this happen?**

Beyond the scope of the question really, but for further investigation:

You mention that your attempt to build the environment throws `stray \376 and \377`. This is octal notation for `\255` and `\254` which is a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) showing that a file uses UTF-16 encoding. UTF-16 (little endian) encoding is also represented by the characters `ÿþ` which you see in your not-symlink. These bits of code will be reported as 'stray' if they occur anywhere other than at the beginning of a file. Windows (NTFS) and other filesystems [use UTF-16 LE encoding for filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) (and the Unicode strings that store their version of symlinks) so this could be happening because parts of the pathnames are in such a filesystem. Again, fix by making new symlinks.

[You can't turn a regular file into a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330543/how-to-turn-a-regular-file-into-a-symlink-on-linux) because in general symlink-ness is metadata stored in the filesystem, in inode tables.

However, since there are [symlink implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Storage_of_symbolic_links) that store the path data inside the file, and this method could be used as a fallback in the event that there are not enough inodes available to store symlink paths, this might have happened because you don't have enough inodes in the partition (have a look with `df -i .`)

Comment: big +1 for efforts

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, but when I execute ls -l in the directory as my video with cygwin, it show  as a symlink: lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrators RD_Design    3 May 18 11:43 g++ -> gcc. You can see my capture cygwin screen in here: http://imgur.com/3NJu7ZS

Comment: How did you make these symlinks? (Windows has completely different symlink mechanisms to Unixoid filesystems...)

Comment: I don't know how it make, my project has already exists it. I clone project by following instruction in [here link](http://www.n-keitai.com/gpl/w/download/GzOne_COMMAND_4G_LTE/jelly_bean/procedure.txt). It was a Android Open Source Project build for Casio GzOne COMMANDO 4G LTE

Comment: Okay well in that case, I don't think either of those files is meant to be run directly. Does the Android Project have insstructions on how to use it once it's installed?

Comment: in Cygwin AND in Ubuntu, what is the output of `file g++` in this directory?

Comment: Dear Zanna:
- When I execute command file g++ in Cygwin, it show "g++: symbolic link to gcc".
And with ubuntu, it show "g++: data". This is image that I captured from window [link image](http://imgur.com/NCJmLEh)

Comment: Dear TallChuck:
- After getting the project, I execute command in step 4 of instruction. When process is running, 
it has error as I asked. In addition, there are many other similar errors. Many header file (file *.h) 
can not be compiled and it throw error :
error: expected identifier or '(' before '!' token 
error: stray '\377' in program 
error: stray '\376' in program

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope you get somewhere with it!

Comment: Thanks you so much, I am very satisfied with your answer ^_^

Comment: ^_^ I'm glad it was helpful, good luck with your project